# Run subset of tests in android via gradle task

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle

I need to run some specific set of tests from different modules in android project. Let's say each test has "ImportantTest" in its name and I want to run all such tests in one run. Not all modules have such tests, but many of them.
I found a command for gradle that can filter tests and tried it:

```
 ./gradlew testDebugUnitTest --tests '*ImportantTest'
```

but it fails with error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':some-module:testDebugUnitTest'.
> No tests found for given includes: [*ImportantTest](--tests filter)
```

obviously because module `some-module` doesn't have such tests, but how can I run tests from all other modules?

I also tried gradle task

```
tasks.register("runImportantTests", Test) {
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching("*ImportantTest")
    }
}
```

but I get an error

```
Gradle build - Could not determine the dependencies of task ':runImportantTests'
```

and cannot understant what kind of dependencies does it need? All docs say you can use this task like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it, all you need is to add next block to all modules with tests that you want to run

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            all {
                test {
                    filter {
                        def testEnv = project.hasProperty('testEnv') ? project.getProperty('testEnv') : null
                        if (configTestEnv != null) {
                            includeTestsMatching "*MyTestSuffixName"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then add custom gradle task

```
boolean checkIfHasConfigTest(File file) {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        false
    } else if (file.isFile()) {
        def configTestNameRegex = ~/.*MyTestSuffixName.*/
        configTestNameRegex.matcher(file.path).find()
    } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
        file.listFiles().any {
            checkIfHasConfigTest(it)
        }
    } else {
        false
    }
}


tasks.register("runMyTests") {
    String testEnv = project.hasProperty('testEnv') ? project.getProperty('testEnv').toString() : null

    if (testEnv != null) {
        Set<String> commands = project.rootProject.subprojects
                .findAll { proj -> checkIfHasConfigTest(new File("${proj.projectDir}/src/test")) }
                .collect { ":${it.name}:test${testEnv}DebugUnitTest" }
        dependsOn(commands)
    }
}
```

Then we can run this command with

```
./gradlew runMyTests -PtestEnv=Dev
```

where Dev is one of the flavors, in case you don't have flavors - just ommit that part from gradle command